# What does ch!=?.? mean in c++

Tags: c++, c

This is used here `do {....} while(ch!=?.?);` what does `ch!=?.?` mean here can anybody please help with it.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in C (or C++).  My best guess would be that the question marks are an open single quote and a close single quote in Unicode, and can't be represented in the font used by your display technology.  You need to use the plain ASCII apostrophe instead — the same character either side of the `.`, so it should look like `(ch!='.')`, or with a little white space, `(ch != '.')`.

Comment: Does that C++ code compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` ?

Comment: @S.M. — they are not trigraphs, if that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Due to my doubts, I googled a bit and can confirm: [Alternative operator representations (C++)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative), [Alternative operators and tokens (C)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative). ;-)

Comment: @S.M. I have make a quick [search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), and there's no "?.?" :-)

Comment: @J in this case ? seems to be a broken quotation mark copied from web.

Comment: I think that website was broken and had " ? " instead of " ' ".

Comment: someone used a common text editor with autoreplace capability to type code. Those editors tend to replace quotation marks with unicode characters which look "better". It breaks syntax. When converted to ASCII, unrepresentable characters are replaced with ?

Comment: Also there could be problems with website's design.  Single quotes have to be represented by `&apos`  code but browser is free to use ANYTHING that looks like apostrophe, not necessary the ASCII character for single quote. Formally, unicode apostrophe is  separate character. Website had to have facilities to represent data\text verbatim and ready for copy\paste, e.g. how Stackexchange\Stackoverflow does it, which is absent in simple cases or on general-purpose platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error with both clang and gcc.

@JonathanLeffler is usually right and I think he nailed the root cause.  I used to see this when text was being copied from Microsoft Word to the web (lack of transcode from a Windows code page to ascii/utf8?).

Comment: MS Word is _the_ best code editor for sure... :)